# IE Scrollbar + Overflow Scroll + div on top of the

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, overflow

I have two divs. One div (copy) has a css overflow property set to auto. The other div (overlay) sits on top. I can not change the z-index of these two divs, because visually the overlay needs to be on top of the copy. In IE9, the scrollbar for the 'copy' div is not clickable/useable. In Chrome, it works fine because I am using the pointer-events property. How can I get this example to work in IE9? I need to be able to scroll the content.

CSS

```
#overlay{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    background-color:#990000;
    z-index:2;
    opacity:.2;
    pointer-events:none;
}
#copy{
    overflow:auto;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index:1;
```

}

HTML

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="copy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus in felis elit. Mauris elementum mi non mauris euismod interdum. Morbi auctor velit lacinia augue vehicula vel egestas tortor scelerisque. Sed quis arcu massa, quis elementum ligula. Nunc et quam id ipsum consequat ullamcorper.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus in felis elit. Mauris elementum mi non mauris euismod interdum. Morbi auctor velit lacinia augue vehicula vel egestas tortor scelerisque. Sed quis arcu massa, quis elementum ligula. Nunc et quam id ipsum consequat ullamcorper.</div>
```

See an example here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/7w4Jh/1/

Remember, the example works fine in webkit browsers. The issue only occurs in Internet Explorer (9)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your z-index is set up for `#overlay` to sit over the top of copy, preventing the underlying `#copy` from receiving mouse events. By switching the z-index of each, it works just fine.

Also, you don't need all three `overflow` properties declared. This will suffice:

```
overflow:hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;
```

Just a heads up.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know why it doesn't work, but I was wondering if there is another solution other than changing the z-index. Visually, I need the overlay div to sit on top of the copy.

Comment: only thing i can think of is using Javascript to tie your mousewheel event on `#overlay` to scrolling on `#copy`.

Comment: That may get the #copy to scroll, which is good, but the user still wont be able to click on the scroll up/down/scrubber buttons.

Comment: well you could always go super hacky and create a custom scrollbar with up/down buttons. set `#copy` to `overflow:hidden`, and write javascript to have the scrolling occur on the clicking of the arrows or on mousewheel move. time-consuming, but its probably your only shot.

Answer (score 0):

`pointer-events`  ([CSS pointer-Events To Allow Clicks On Underlying Elements](http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/22/css-pointer-events-to-allow-clicks-on-underlying-elements/)) **not working in IE..**

i found :

[forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/)

and

http://jsbin.com/uhuto

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unless I am mistaken, I do not believe that technique works for the scrollbar. It is great to use to determine what div is click on and firing the corresponding event.